# "Linked Item" Lookup available in browser by not SPD2010?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, lookup-column, site-column

When I create a Lookup site column in the Browser, this enables me to choose "linked to item"...which then means it pulls back all the related information.

However, if I do the same in SPD 2010, there is no "Linked to Item" option?

[image: Browser]

[image: SPD2010]

Is there a different way to create a linked column in SPD, or are there other things that the browser can do, but SPD2010 can't?  (or vice versa?)

Comment: I have noticed there are things the browser can do that SPD2010 cannot, for example, adding a column to a list (in a subsite) that references a site column (whose instance is in a parent site) doesn't seem to work with SPD2010 but it does work with the browser.

Comment: Hmm...I'd expected it to be the other way around!  Guess I should use the browser as the main tool.  Any idea if there are things SPD can do that the browser cannot?

Comment: Does "Linked Item" really make a difference anyway? It's just LinkTitle, the computed field of Title, which will not render as a link in your lookup anyway

Comment: The "Linked Item" means that it displays the other properties of my "Customer" record on the Item.  Otherwise these remain blank.